# Python string swap formatting

Tags: python

I need to swap the list of names which is in the format of FirstName and LastName which in a dataframe one column, using python.

Below is the sample format:
~Adam Smith

The above need to change into 
~Smith Adam

Is there any single line function available in python?

Could anyone help on this!!

Comment: This is a trivial task. What did you try? Please include your code.

Comment: `print( " ".join(reversed("Adam Smith".split())))`

Comment: `df.name.str.split().apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[::-1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"names": ["Adam Smith", "Greg Rogers"]})
df["names"] = df["names"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(reversed(x.split()))) 
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
         names
0   Smith Adam
1  Rogers Greg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: I need a help on string manipulation on dataframes